# What is the proper term for a "Gas Powered Post Driver"

Tags: traduction

Vous recherchez essentiellement le terme approprié pour ce produit?

[image: Gas Powered Post Driver]

Y aurait-il une différence entre Canadien et Parisien?

Merci

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On trouve le nom *enfonce-pieux*, et de là *enfonce-pieux thermique* , ou *enfonce-pieux à essence*, *enfonce-pieux à moteur essence*, *enfonce-pieux moteur essence*, etc.

Un exemple [ici](https://www.monstershop.eu/fr/maison-jardin/amenagement-exterieur-jardinage/enfonce-pieux-a-essence)

Answer (score 1):

Les outils ayant un moteur à essence sont généralement appelés 'thermiques' (par opposition à 'électriques') : une tronçonneuse thermique et une tronçonneuse électrique.

Answer (score 0):

On trouve quatres variantes pour le nom français et elles seraient apparemment valides aussi au Canada puisque les noms proviennent de Amazon et de Alibaba.

Le nom français serait « pilote de poteau à essence » (voir cette [annonce](https://www.amazon.fr/Pilote-poteau-essence-temps-T-Mech/dp/B07DD4MP8W)).

On trouve aussi « Conducteur de poteau de clôture et poteau de clôture électrique » (voir [annonce](https://french.alibaba.com/trade/search?fsb=y&IndexArea=products&CatId=&SearchText=pilote+poteau+canada&selectedTab=products&viewType=GALLERY)).

Un autre nom est « Marteau Conducteur Portatif À Essence » .

Il y a aussi « marteau pile driver ».

Comment: De manière générale, je méfierais des traductions Amazon et Alibaba, les vendeurs y utilisent souvent Google Translate aveuglement, avec des résultats parfois loufoques.

Comment: Ta "maîtrise" du français se manifeste une fois encore par : *proviennent **de** Amazon et **de** Alibaba*...